# Are there resources that categorize verses from Prasthanatrayi, mainly Upanishads, for the study of Advaita Vedanta?

Tags: advaita, upanishads, adi-shankaracharya

I'm looking for sources that have compiled verses from Upanishads or Prakarana Grantha based on a broad outline of Advaita Vedanta.
For instance, verses related to - Brahman, Maya, Ishvara, Avastha-traya etc.

One finds such cheatsheets online for Bible study, so I was wondering if there are similar sources for Advaita Vedanta.

Comment: This consolidation is done by a renowned Advaita Scholar Shri S N Saastri , available in this site    http://www.advaita.org.uk/discourses/s_n_sastri/vedanta.pdf
    Hope this would be helpful

Comment: @Athrey Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes,it is called the Brahma Sutras. Several versions here - https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda What is your opinion on V M Apte's translation of Brahma Sutra Sankara Bhashya?